# Zooming bug in html page

Tags: html, css, user-interface

so i have been working on my portfolio website recently and I noticed that my elements sizes are very big in laptop screens, so i tried using:

```css
body {
  zoom: 90%
}
```

to decrease sizes of elements and the page, and yes it worked, But all the content in the page went to the top and off the screen a little bit.

How do I fix that?

Comment: use `media queries`! A good point to read into `responsive web design` instead of applying a hacky `zoom` instead of applying `responsive web design`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `height: 100vh` on elements without thinking about how it affects widescreen aspect ratios?